# QI is returning E_NOINTERFACE when querying for IAMStreamConfig

Tags: c++, directshow

I'm trying to retrieve the `IAMStreamConfig` interface from the output pin on my Integrated Camera, but am failing to `E_NOINTERFACE`.

I'm using the IntCam as a testing device, in reality I will have a source filter with two output pins that each support different configurations.

This is why I'm not sure using `ICaptureGraphBuilder2::FindInterface` is an option, because I still haven't figured out how I will be able to get the interface from a specific output pin.

```
CComPtr<IEnumPins> pEnum = NULL;
IPin* pPin = NULL;

HRESULT hr = pFilter->EnumPins(&pEnum);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;

while (S_OK == pEnum->Next(1, &pPin, NULL))
{
   IAMStreamConfig* pAMStreamConfig;
   hr = pPin->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pAMStreamConfig));
   if (FAILED(hr))
      return hr;
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Your code gives up quickly.  If another pin implements it then you won't find it.

Comment: The code is an example. In any case, there is only one output pin on the IntCam and it does implement it.

Comment: Then beware of threads.  You might be talking to a proxy, it fails with the same error code if the proxy doesn't know how to marshal the interface.  I don't see one registered for IAMStreamConfig when I look in the registry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IAMStreamConfig` is not a mandatory interface, it might me missing, though on camera filters it is almost always available (many application would refuse working with a device without this interface otherwise). That is, you should double check that you are querying correct filter and pin, the code snippet looks good.

A real camera is most often implemented via [`WDM Video Capture Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which has `IAMStreamConfig` but since you are using a virtual device, it might be different.

Comment: I'm sure the filter and pins are correct. The integrated camera implements this interface, I can open the property page in GraphEdit when clicking properties on the pin. This is why it's so stumbling

Comment: There is no reason for it to be missing or otherwise unexpectedly unavailable to you. You might want to check it with [AMCap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Wnidows SDK sample, or [another app that outputs capabilities of a video device](http://trac.assembla.com/roatl-utilities/browser/trunk/EnumerateVideoCaptureFilterCapabilities).

Comment: You can check your device with [GraphStudioNext](http://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/). It lists all supported standard interfaces for filters and pins (Right click on pin or filter -> Properties -> Tab Interfaces)

Comment: To simulate my 2 pin device, I was connecting the IntCam to an Infinite splitter, and was trying to QI on the splitter pins instead of the cam pins.. my mistake